# Setting OneToOne relationship in entity with inheritance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, relational-database, one-to-one

I created abstract class Entity (I want to create different types of shapes):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class ShapeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    @OneToOne
    private ShapeDetailsEntity shapeDetailsEntity;

    public abstract double getArea();

    public abstract double getPerimeter();
}
```

and I want to every add to every entity table with details:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "shape_details")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ShapeDetailsEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "shapeDetailsEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ShapeEntity shapeEntity;
```

The logic of creating entites is in service:

```
public class ShapeService {
    public ShapeEntity createShape(ShapeType type, List<Double> parameters) {
        switch (type) {
            case CIRCLE:
                return circleEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(new CircleEntity(parameters));
            case SQUARE:
                return squareEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(new SquareEntity(parameters));
            case RECTANGLE:
                return rectangleEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(new RectangleEntity(parameters));
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

and now for tests in controller I would like to create new entity - in comments I put response in console:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> post(@Valid @RequestBody ShapeRequestModel shapeRequestModel) {
    ShapeEntity shapeEntity = shapeService.createShape(ShapeType.valueOf(shapeRequestModel.getType()), shapeRequestModel.getParameters());
    ShapeDetailsEntity shapeDetailsEntity = shapeService.createShapeDetails(shapeEntity);
    System.out.println(shapeDetailsEntity.getShapeEntity().toString()); // -> CircleEntity{radius=4.5}
    System.out.println(shapeDetailsEntity); // -> ShapeDetailsEntity{all details...}
    System.out.println(shapeEntity.getShapeDetailsEntity().toString()); // -> java.lang.NullPointerException: null

    return new ResponseEntity<>(shapeEntity.toString(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

in **shapeService.createShapeDetails(shapeEntity)**  looks like:

```
 public ShapeDetailsEntity createShapeDetails(ShapeEntity shapeEntity) {
    ShapeDetailsEntity shapeDetailsEntity = new ShapeDetailsEntity();
    shapeDetailsEntity.setShapeEntity(shapeEntity);
    return shapeDetailsEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(shapeDetailsEntity);
}
```

How should I do it correctly to not getting null in
**shapeEntity.getShapeDetailsEntity().toString())**
? In database place when should be id of shapeDetailsEntity I am getting null.

Answer (score 0):

The `ShapeEntity` you are creating has no `ShapeDetailsEntity` assigned i.e. the field is null, so that's why you get a NPE. If you don't want that, you have to assign an object to that field.

IMO, this `shapeService.createShapeDetails(shapeEntity);` code shouldn't be necessary. Your `ShapeService.createShape` method should assign a `ShapeDetailsEntity` object to the field.